# jQuery Cycle: delaying "click-to-pause"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

On my slideshow, if the slide is clicked it will pause. But I want to disable the ability to click-to-pause until **after** the first slide transition (the title slide). Right now the "#slideshow" div is clickable as soon as the DOM is ready; too soon for me.

An abridged version of what I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#slideshow img').toggle(function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle('pause');
  }, function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle('resume');
  });

  $('#slideshow').cycle({
        /*options*/
  });

});
```

Comment: As a sidenote, the `toggle()` function used that way is actually deprecated. You could of course just place your event handler inside a timeout function.

Comment: Hmm, don't see where it says toggle is deprecated (on api.jquery.com). What should be used instead?

Comment: @Adam http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ (see Categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just bind the `.toggle` function (or change to `.click` since `.toggle` is deprecated for this use) with the `after` option of `.cycle`.

Comment: Thanks that works. Deprecated or not though, toggle is much more convenient for an element that will never need to be un-binded and has no href.